# Do I put the following parts in "non functional needs"?

Tags: specifications, requirements

I am writing a *user requirements document* for an application. 
I distinguished two chapters: one for *functional needs* and another for *non functional needs*.

In the functional needs, I enumerated a list of functional spec. 
Actually, I am confronted to the following situation : I have to talk about :

- User interface
- Performance
- security
- Data format

Do I put those parts in *Non functional needs* ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question (and my answer) is a rather subjective one as people can have different opinions and there is no true accepted standard here but I try to explain my reasoning nevertheless.

The required (or implemented) data format is definitely a functional requirement as it defines how your application communicates with others. The other requirements are traditionally considered non-functional but in practivce, you can get bit philosophical here as there is no One True Answer.

Traditionally, things like performance, security or the look of an application were considered non-functional requirements and were thus effectively demoted to the afterthoughts or nice-to-haves.

In my opinion, this is fundamentally wrong. By extension, I think this distinction is flawed and should not be made in the first place. Depending on your application, different things (or features) are more important than others but often, the traditionally non-functional requirements can make or break an application.

For example, a messaging system can look as nice as it can, if it is not secure and leaks messages, it is useless. Similarly, a computer game that is fast and secure but doesn't look nice and isn't easy to understand will probably not worth much (there are exceptions). Thus, traditionally non-functional requirements can be very well an important part of the provided functionality.

The best example is this very website where you are asking your question. The prime non-functional requirement is performance. It is generally considered nice to have, not not planned into the product and not considered a core-functionality. On Stack Overflow (and other stack exchange sites), performance is considered one of the main features and the developers consider a slow page to not be functional.

Another example is in the UI/UX space. Commonly, you considered the behaviour of a user interface (the function) separate from the look (the non-function). But if you look at e.g. smartphone apps or web apps, you will often find that the user experience is defined by both the exact behaviour and the design which can't be separated as both are strongly connected and significantly affect each other.

Thus, for my conclusion: You should think about your actual requirements in terms of what you want your application to provide. The distinction between functional and non-functional is rather useless as it doesn't help you to define what is important and what not. Instead, focus on your values and define the user experience you want to provide (both to end-users as well as developers, administrators, ...)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, I retain one important thing : I have to put focus on the content, not bother my self with functional and non-functional because th limit is not so crisp :)

Comment: Can you suggest some reference to master the writing of *user requirements document* ?

Comment: Here is a simple yet very effective source. http://reqtest.com/requirements-blog/functional-vs-non-functional-requirements/

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @(Holger Just) especially with

> Traditionally, things like performance, security or the look of an application were considered non-functional requirements and were thus effectively demoted to the afterthoughts or nice-to-haves.

However I would like to add a few notes.

The distinction between functional and non-functional test sometimes is useful. The performance and security testing domains are different from the functional testing domain. These non-functional tests usually included in the special test discipline and require different technical skills and sometimes organized in the different teams. For example performance test requires knowledge in the performance tests tools and techniques(like JMeter or/and CPU and memory profilers). The security test also is big domain itself and includes knowledge about the threat modeling and penetration testing.

Also I would distinct between rude bugs in performance and security that have influence on the product functionality and performance and security testing that allow to understand the product level in these areas. For example the performance test launched every build may indicate some performance product degradation (even in 10 ms) that usually not measurable in the functional testing.